# Create a HTML table with an ASP repeater, repeating horizontally

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, repeater

I'm trying to build a HTML table using an ASP repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterVersionsForPie" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table id="VersionsTable" >

                <tr>
                    <th>
                    <%#Eval("nameVersion")%>
                    </th>

                </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td tag="<%#Eval("idVersion")%>">
                    <%#Eval("NumberOfCompaniesUsingThisVersion")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is a basic table which consists in **two lines and X columns**.
The second line appears without any problems while the first one is invisible.
Can anyone help to find what's missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just convert first ItemTemplate into HeaderTemplate (typing mistake?)

Comment: I had already tried to use HeaderTemplate instead but it's not working neither, i don't understand why ...

Comment: Change that to HeaderTemplate and have a look at the error panel of the browser (Ctrl+Shift+J for Firefox)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the core problem is that `Repeater` isn't designed to repeat horizontally.

Maybe you should try using [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx) which allows to specify the RepeatingDirection.

**Update**

If you don't need to repeat horizontally (like your question suggests "...two lines and X columns") your `Repeater`should look like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterVersionsForPie" runat="server">

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="VersionsTable">
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th><%# Eval("nameVersion") %></th>
            <!-- Important: Put attributes in single quotes so they don't get
                 mixed up with your #Eval("xxx") double quotes! -->
            <td tag='<%#Eval("idVersion")%>'>
                <%# Eval("DocumentName") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Note that you must not repeat the `<table>` in your `<ItemTemplate>` and to use single quotes when you need to put your `Eval` inside an attribute.

Comment: Thanks but anyway this is not a serious problem is the table is built vertically.
How come it's not working ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use multiple instances of the ItemTemplate tag. You can only use one of each tag that is available with the Repeater controls.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemtemplate?view=netframework-4.8